# What does the colon in Tikz coordinates mean?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\draw (0,0) -- (60:.75cm) arc (60:180:.75cm);
```

What does the colon in `(60:.75cm)` mean? Normally, I'd define a normal point there.

Comment: Figured it out and wrote a neat answer, but apparently I can't post it within 8 h of asking, it told me AFTER letting me write the answer!! (this is a bug report)

Comment: That's hilarious, the same second!

Comment: @Werner Well, that's a first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The colon signifies that polar coordinates are being used. `(60:.75cm)` means the point that is at an angle of 60° and a distance of 0.75cm from the origin.

In the [TikZ/PGF manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) this is mentioned in section **13.2 Coordinate Systems**, p 125:

> The implicit form for `canvas polar` coordinates is the following: you specify the angle and the distance, separated by a colon as in `(30:1cm)`.

This also holds for other coordinate systems like `xyz polar`. Alternatively, if you're not interested in this shorthand notation, TikZ also provides

```
\pgfpointpolar{<degree>}{<x-radius>/<y-radius>}
```

where `<y-radius>` is optional. See section **70 Specifying Coordinates** (p 571) of the documentation.

Comment: "If the optional `y-radius` is given, the polar coordinate is actually a coordinate on an ellipse whose `x-radius` is given by `x-radius` and whose `y-radius` is given by `y-radius`."