# TikZ set node label position more precisely

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

This seems like it should be really easy but I can't seem to find it anywhere...

I'd like to be able to fine-tune the positioning of a node label.

I'm aware of the `\node[label=above/below/etc:{label}] (x) {};` syntax, but that doesn't seem to give you many options on where the label goes. I'd like to be able to place the label slightly closer or farther away, or maybe in a direction other than the 8 presets available.

`\tikz[label distance=x]` isn't a good solution because I need it to be node-specific.

Comment: Similar problem: [How can I force TikZ pin angle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/how-can-i-force-tikz-pin-angle)

Comment: I completed the answer with positioning

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can define the direction of the label by using `label=<angle>:<label text>`. To specify the distance on a per node distance, you have to supply it to the `label` options: `label={[label distance=<distance>]<angle>:<label text>}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style=draw,
    every label/.style=draw
]
\node [label={[label distance=1cm]30:label}] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Does the label text need to be in braces? I found mine did, but that may have been because I was specifying color and size options.

Comment: They only need to be in braces if you supply options using `[...]`, because you need to mask the `[` and `]`. If you're only supplying angle and text, you can just use `label=20:text`.

Comment: What is the default label distance if you only write above, below, right or left?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: It's zero, the gap between the node contents only comes from the `inner sep` and `outer sep` of the node and label node. You can see this using `\node [draw, label={[draw]above:Top}] {Bottom};`, for example.

Comment: @Jake Is there a way to add a connecting line between the node and the line? This could be helpful in crammed circumstances to make it clear which label belongs to which node.

Comment: @Casimir: Sure, that's what `pin` is for: `pin={[pin distance=1cm]30:label}`

Comment: @Jake Cool! Can the label position w.r.t. to the connecting line be customized? When I use it, the line seems to end well below the label.

Comment: @Casimir: This is probably due to the `inner sep` padding of the `pin` node. Try setting `every pin/.style=draw` to see where the space comes from, or `every pin/.style={inner sep=0pt}` to remove the padding.

Comment: `inner sep=0pt` did the trick. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Any hints on how to do so with `tkz-euclide` (`\tkzLabelAngle`)?

Comment: can distance be negative?

Answer (score 71):

Good to know all the other ways to do this, but I have always used `xshift=<length>`, and `yshift=<length>` to move a `node` or `label`.

The blue is the default, and the red is with the option `[xshift=1.0cm, yshift=0.3cm]`, and the green  (as suggested by percusse) is using an alternate syntax to specify the x and y shift as a vector `[shift={(1.0,0.3)}]`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
    \node [label={Label}] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
    \node [label={[xshift=1.0cm, yshift=0.3cm]Label}] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[green]
    \node [label={[shift={(1.0,0.3)}]Label}] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `shift={(1,0.3}}` syntax might also be included if you wish.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks have updated the solution to include the alternate syntax.

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for how the default (blue) label position is determined?

Comment: @A.Ellett: I assume it is documented in the [TikZ/PGF documentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49698/tikz-manual-newest-version-online). Perhaps you should post a new question on this.

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way is to use another node. Like you wrote, the label is a node "label". In `\path ... node[⟨options⟩](⟨name⟩)at(⟨coordinate⟩){⟨text⟩} ...;`the real label is `⟨text⟩`. Now it's easy to add a node and a new label without the `label` option.

```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document} 

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node [draw,circle ] (a) { Real label}; 
     \node  at (a.60) {$\bullet$}; 
     \node [draw] at ([shift={(95:1)}]a.60) {Second label};

   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
```

[image]

The only problem is that you need to give the name first node but you can do what you want. In the first version of TikZ, without the `label` option it was the only way.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a comma: `={(95,1)}` instead of a semicolon: `={(95:1)}`?

Comment: The colon in `(95:1)` signifies that polar coordinates are being used. In this case it means that the point is at an angle of 95° and a distance of 1(cm) from the origin. See also: [What does the colon in Tikz coordinates mean?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47173/101831)

Comment: what about the red dot in the centre

Answer (score 16):

The library "positioning" allows easy positioning of nodes with each other

La librairie "positioning"  permet un positionnement facile et rapide des noeuds les uns par rapport aux autres

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style=draw,
    every label/.style=draw
]
\node (node) {Node};
\foreach \xx/\yy in {1/2,-1/3,5/0,-3/-2,0/0}{
\node [above right = \xx cm and \yy cm of node](label){Label\xx\yy};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image displaying the positioned labels in code]

[fr] je complète la réponse pour répondre pour préciser le positionnement d'un label et pas seulement d'un noeud

[en] I complete the answer to answer to clarify the positioning of a label and not just a node

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style=draw,
    every label/.style=draw
]
\foreach \xx/\yy in {1/2,-1/3,5/0,-3/-2,0/0}{
\node [label={[above right = \xx cm and \yy cm of node]:label\xx\yy}] (node) {Node};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot showing the result of the second code snippet]

[fr] on remarque que l'origine du positionnement n'est pas le même que pour les noeuds

[en] we note that the origin of the Positioning is not the same as for nodes

Comment: This is about node positioning, whereas my question pertained to label positioning

Comment: I completed the answer with positioning

Comment: Excellent answer. The title has "node label position" and google takes you here whether you want to position the label or the node. Very useful to have here.

Answer (score 9):

This pattern is also quite useful:

```
\node at ($(R) + (0.03,0.4)$)    {Your label!};
```

This way you can position the label relative to the coordinates of `R`.

Note that you need `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` for this way.

A similar solution that does not require `calc` (thanks [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit)!) is

```
\path (R) ++(0.03,0.4) node {Your label!};
```

Comment: Without `calc`: `\path (R) ++(0.03,0.4) node {Your label!};`

Comment: even saving a plus sign `\path (R) +(.03,.4) node {Your label!};` ^^