# How to set node label position with anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Actually, I write some notes about *programming with Tikz* and reading Jake's answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58878/tikz-set-node-label-position-more-precisely), I asked myself  how tikz places the "node label".

I would like to reproduce:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node [circle,draw] (c){Circle};
\node[red,anchor=base,text=red,fill=white] at (c.60)  {$C_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with a "node label"

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

What I want:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node [circle,draw] (c){Circle};
\node[red,anchor=base,text=red,fill=white] at (c.60)  {$C_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

What I tried:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node [circle,draw,label={[text=red,fill=white,anchor=base]60:$C_1$}] (c){Circle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`anchor=base` does not give the desired result. Do you know a trick or a workaround to move the "node label"? I can use `shift={(-2ex,-2ex)` but it's not very funny.

I read the manual **16.10.2 The Label Option cvs version** and I found only this (the sentence is strange: "an anchor point for the label node  is determined" seems better)

> Then, an anchor point for the label node. It is determined in such a
>   way that the label node will “face away” from the border of the main
>   node. The anchor that is chosen depends on the position of the border
>   point that is chosen and its position relative to the center of the
>   main node and on whether the transform shape option is set. In
>   general, the choice should be what you would expect, but you may have
>   to set the anchor yourself in difficult situations.

But this does not give me a answer.

I never really liked this option `label= ...` as this is perhaps why I'm missing a simple solution.

Comment: Related: [How can I set the tikz label anchor explicitly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106791) and [chat discussion about first linked question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8806751#8806751); `\tikz@anchor@auto` makes also the “snapping” to certain angles/anchors.

Comment: Thank you, I had not seen or found this question. My question is duplicated

Comment: For curiosity I tested also the style `my label` from the "revised" answer I provided to [How can I set the tikz label anchor explicitly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106791/13304): basically it works, but in order to be comparable with Qrrbrbirlbel's nice approach, it needs some improvement since now the "distance" between the center anchor is fixed.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I need to close or to delete the question ?

Comment: I don’t think there’s any need to delete. Closing will just do. You can also edit the question to create a Follow-Up. :)