# How to give label to Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to label each vertices of Fano hypergraph with v1,v2, . . . ,v7 but I don't know how to label its Fano hypergraph. This is what I have done :

```
  \newcommand\FanoPlane[1][1cm]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
     mydot/.style={
     draw,
     circle,
     fill=black,
     inner sep=3pt}
]
 \draw
 (0,0) coordinate (A) --
 (#1,0) coordinate (B) --
 ($ (A)!.5!(B) ! {sin(60)*2} ! 90:(B) $) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
\coordinate (O) at
   (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1);
\draw (O) circle [radius=#1*1.717/6];
\draw (C) -- ($ (A)!.5!(B) $) coordinate (LC); 
\draw (A) -- ($ (B)!.5!(C) $) coordinate (LA); 
\draw (B) -- ($ (C)!.5!(A) $) coordinate (LB); 
\foreach \Nodo in {A,B,C,O,LC,LA,LB}
\node[mydot] at (\Nodo) {};    
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\quad\FanoPlane[5cm]
\caption{An example of a hypergraph, with $X= \{ v_1, v_2, ..., v_7 \}$} and $E= \{e_1, e_2, . . ., e_7 \}= \{ \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}, \{v_1,v_4,v_5\}, \{v_1,v_6,v_7\}, \{v_2,v_4,v_6\}, \{v_2,v_5,v_7\},\{v_3,v_4,v_7\}, \{v_3,v_5, v_6\}\}$      \label{fig:figurelabel}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment. - Helpful and related is: [TikZ set node label position more precisely](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58878/124842)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to modify the `\foreach` loop to

```
\foreach [count=\i] \Nodo/\pos in {A/left,B/right,C/left,O/left,LC/below,LA/right,LB/left}
  \node[mydot,label=\pos:$v_\i$] at (\Nodo) {};
```

The `\foo/\bar` syntax lets you have two loop variables. Here, one for the node name, the other for the position of the label relative to the node. `count` is just what it says, a counter for the number of times the loop has run.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\FanoPlane[1][1cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={
     draw,
     circle,
     fill=black,
     inner sep=3pt}
]
 \draw
 (0,0) coordinate (A) --
 (#1,0) coordinate (B) --
 ($ (A)!.5!(B) ! {sin(60)*2} ! 90:(B) $) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
\coordinate (O) at
   (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1);
\draw (O) circle [radius=#1*1.717/6];
\draw (C) -- ($ (A)!.5!(B) $) coordinate (LC); 
\draw (A) -- ($ (B)!.5!(C) $) coordinate (LA); 
\draw (B) -- ($ (C)!.5!(A) $) coordinate (LB); 
\foreach [count=\i] \Nodo/\pos in {A/left,B/right,C/left,O/left,LC/below,LA/right,LB/left}
  \node[mydot,label=\pos:$v_\i$] at (\Nodo) {};   
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\FanoPlane[5cm]
\end{document}
```