# Set precise label position in metapost

Tags: metapost, metafun

Is there any option(s) in METAPOST (and/or METAFUN) to label things like TikZ allows it for [nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58880/213111)?

Of course I know about `label.{top|bot|lft|rt|...}` but is there something more precise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `freelabel(label, point, point_origin)` macro of Metafun. Not the same kind of labels as in tikz, but it can help.

It sets the `label` upon the straight line `point_origin--point`, near `point` but on the opposite side of `point_origin`.

A very quick example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibsetformat{metafun}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
        u := 3cm;
        draw fullcircle scaled (2u);
        for i = 0 upto 14:
            draw origin -- u*dir 24i;
            freelabel("$" & decimal 24i & "$", u*dir 24i, origin);
        endfor;
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the [Metafun documentation](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf) (p. 453 and following) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

One could extend the `thefreelabel` from [metafun](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) to put the labels in the direction one wants. It is the `freelabeloffset` that determines how far from the point the label is set.

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
vardef dirlabel(expr s, l, d) = 
    thefreelabel(s,l, unitvector dir(d+180) shifted l)
enddef ;

path p ; p = (origin -- (1,0) .. (2,2) .. (0,1) .. cycle) scaled 100 ;
numeric N ; N := 20 ;

draw p ;

for i = 0 upto (N - 1) :
    draw point i/N along p withpen pencircle scaled 2  withcolor darkred ;
    draw dirlabel(decimal i, point i/N along p, angle(direction (arctime ((i/N)*arclength p) of p) of p) - 90) ;
endfor ;
\stopMPpage
```

[image: a path with labels along it]