how to label a tikz path, where the node label extends outward perpendicular to the path at a point
I want to label a path in TikZ where the label comes out at a specified distance, perpendicular to the path at a point along its length.
I can currently place nodes along a path at arbitrary angles from the node as in the following diagram and code (credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58880/319072). And while I could manually calculate these angle values for each path, that would be no fun. I looked at Tikz: label of node, midway perpendicular to the node, but wanted to streamline the approach.
The label needs to come out perpendicular to the path at a point along it. Does anyone know how to do this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|->] (0,0) -- (5,3) node[pos=0.33,label={[label distance=1cm]-60:a label}] {};
\draw[|->] (0,1) arc[start angle=270, end angle=60, radius=3] node[pos=0.5,label={[label distance=1cm]120:another label}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|->] (0,0) -- (5,3) node[pos=0.33, sloped, rotate=-90, anchor=west] {a label};
\draw[|->] (0,1) arc[start angle=270, end angle=60, radius=3] node[pos=0.5, sloped, rotate=-90, anchor=east] {another label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Realised that the node should not be sticking out but only placed at a position perpendicular away from the curve. I do not know if there is a simpler way:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
|->,
decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.33 with {\node[anchor=east] at (0,1) {a label};}},
postaction={decorate},
] (0,0) -- (5,3);
\draw[
|->,
decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[anchor=east] at (0,1) {another label};}},
postaction={decorate},
] (0,1) arc[start angle=270, end angle=60, radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Is there a  way to keep the labels level? I understand that using sloped and rotate=90 allows us  to use a NESW anchor, but it leaves the labels not standing up straight. Do you know of a way to overcome this?

I do not know what you mean by "level" and "not standing up straight". Can you explain?

I think I know now - working on a solution.

Using sloped or rotate causes the labels to not be in the same orientation as they were originally. Is there a way to restore the orientation of the label so that it can be read in the same orientation as other text?
