# Draw a circle with a pointed radius using tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I would like you to help me create this graphic. I would like to be able to use this one as an example for other graphics that I have to do. 
[image]

Comment: Have you had a look through the TikZ manual?  It's unfortunately long, but you should be able to find the pieces you need.  We tend to frown on "do this for me" type requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be obtained by truncating one of the previous answers you received. In your previous questions, you were able to provide an MWE. What happened to this ability?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$\lambda_0$](z0) {}
circle (pi);
\draw[-stealth] (z0) -- (10:pi) node[midway,above]{$r$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again marmot. I will edit part of your code to complete this graph. I will upload my last result here so you see it!

Comment: The colon in this answer signifies that polar coordinates are being used. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47173/71097