# Connecting circles clockwise in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I need this to work with any `\n` I decide to set in TikZ (because the diagram at this point is undetermined). I don't mind setting `margin` manually, but no arcs except the one from node 3 to 4 connect correctly, and I'm clearly not good at working with polar coordinates.

This is a modified version of http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/, except I would like for it to **start on the left**, and it needs to be **clockwise**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8.2} % margin in angles, depends on the radius
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47172/what-does-the-colon-in-tikz-coordinates-mean
% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
\node[draw, circle] at ({180 - 360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s$};
\draw[->, >=latex] ({180 - 360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:\radius) 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175016/how-is-arc-defined-in-tikz
  arc ({2*\margin}:{-(180/\n)  + 2* \margin }:(\radius * 1.5);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius
\foreach \s in {1,...,\n} {
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n*(1-\s)}:-\radius) {\s};
  \draw[-latex] ({360/\n*(1-\s)-\margin}:-\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n*(1-\s)-\margin}:{-360/\n*\s+\margin}:-\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283917/121799), this is a tree, and such trees understand `clockwise`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw},
level 1/.style={sibling angle=72,level distance=pi*1cm},
edge from parent/.style= {draw=none}]
\coordinate (Center)  [clockwise from=270]
    child foreach \X in {1,...,5} { node[circ] (\X) {\X}};
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially 5)] in  {1,...,5}
{\draw[-latex] (\LastX) to[bend left=28] (\X);}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Following the [example you linked](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/), you can change the degree at which nodes are drawn and the direction of the arrowhead in `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\n - \s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s$};
  \draw[<-, =>latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: It is 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1, not 1 -> 5... It is not that easy

Comment: Just replace `\draw[<-, >=latex]... ` by `\draw[-latex] ...`?

Comment: @marmot, thanks for the tip!

Comment: This solution does not start the first node at the left, and does not have clockwise arcs.

Comment: @JouleV fair enough. I obviously did not provide the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, I just see. It is okay now - downvote retracted